Accessing an out of range element in an array
I have an array with 6 elements, but when I try to access arr[6], it gives me a garbage value instead of array overflow error. What is the reason behind this?
#include <iostream>

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int arr[] = {3, 2, 1, 56, 10000, 167};
    cout << "Value: " << arr[6];
    
    return 0;
}


That’s the way the language is designed. C and C++ don’t check the bounds of their arrays due to performance. You hit what’s called undefined behavior

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

If you want bounds-checking, use std::vector or std::array, and use their at() functions to access elements.

In C++, accessing an array element out of bounds is undefined behaviour- so (loosely) an implementation (compiler, library, runtime) is not required to detect, diagnose, or produce any particular result.  A junk value or a program crash are both equally correct.  Two common reasons for undefined behaviour are (1) difficult to diagnose (e.g. if a pointer is passed to a function, and dereferenced, that can't be diagnosed without visibility of both caller and callee)  (2) detecting the problem at runtime has an undesirable and often unnecessary (if code is properly designed) performance impact

You need to manually opt in bounds checks (which you usually only enable while developing, not in releases). Look up "address sanitizer".

Side note: undefined behaviour

As a side note, I don't know what that bits/stdc++.h is -- it's not a standard header, and it doesn't seem to include anything useful anyway, so I just removed it.
Now, observe:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -Wall Test.cpp
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -Wall -O2 Test.cpp
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:9:31: warning: array subscript 6 is above array bounds of ‘int [6]’ [-Warray-bounds]
    9 |     cout << "Value: " << arr[6];
      |                               ^
Test.cpp:8:9: note: while referencing ‘arr’
    8 |     int arr[] = {3, 2, 1, 56, 10000, 167};
      |         ^~~

So yeah, once you get into optimization, the compiler can detect simple bugs like this already.
Although I'm slightly confused that it needs optimization for this; it's very well possible that other compilers give the warning even without optimizing (since it knows the arraysize, and the index is a compiletime constant...).
However, a better solution would be
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int,6> arr{3, 2, 1, 56, 10000, 167};
    std::cout << "Value: " << arr[6];
    return 0;
}

Still just the compiler complaining:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -Wall -O2 Test.cpp
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:8:36: warning: array subscript 6 is outside array bounds of ‘std::array<int, 6> [1]’ [-Warray-bounds]
    8 |     std::cout << "Value: " << arr[6];
      |                                    ^
Test.cpp:7:23: note: at offset 24 into object ‘arr’ of size 24
    7 |     std::array<int,6> arr{3, 2, 1, 56, 10000, 167};
      |                       ^~~

But, you can now replace the line with something else:
    std::cout << "Value: " << arr.at(6);

stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -Wall -O2 Test.cpp && ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  array::at: __n (which is 6) >= _Nm (which is 6)
Aborted

Basically, C++ does as you tell it: if you don't want bounds-checking, you aren't getting bounds checking.
As a simple example, if you do something like
for (size_t i=0; i<arr.size(); i++)
{
   ... arr[i] ...
}

you know that you're not getting out of bounds, so why check? That's the kind of mindset that a lot of the C++ is built on.

C and C++ don't perform bounds checking on arrays.  That's part of what makes them fast.
However, if you do access past the end of an array, you trigger undefined behavior in your code.  It could crash, it could output strange results, or it could appear to work properly.
